# Need a lightweight web server for Windows XP Home

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I need recommendations for a "light weight web server" to be ran on a Windows XP Home edition system to host a small web service (not web pages - but web service).

The web service can be written in either .NET or Java.  The Windows XP Home system will serve up the web service to clients consuming the service.

Any suggestions? (before it's asked, no, I can't replace the Windows XP home system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java, [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) seems to fit the bill.

Having said that, very few web servers are "heavyweight" on modern hardware. Apache or Tomcat wouldn't strain your machine too much.

Comment: We use Jetty embedded. Really nice, and it scales well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Cassini](http://www.asp.net/Downloads/archived/cassini/) sample that comes with visual studio. It's essentially what is used in VS as the development host server when you are debugging asp.net pages directly in VS.

There is also the more advanced [UltiDev Cassini 2.0](http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/) that was built using the original MS Cassini as a starting point.

Both are obviously written in .net

Answer (score 0):

On WinXP Home, here are a few choices:

- install a virtual machine environment. Then install a guest OS like Windows 2003.
- you *could* install IIS on WinXP home, [after some hacks](http://adamv.com/dev/articles/iis-on-xp-home/)

If you're leaning towards Java, you may have a few more options like:

- [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) with [modifications for SOAP](http://netlinxinc.com/netlinx-blog/51-development/66-building-lightthpd-as-a-soap-server.html)
- [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)

Answer (score -1):

XP home is going to cause you a ton of problems in the long run; if your site gets a significant amount of traffic it's going to be a real headache.

That being said, I'd go with Apache for a plain webserver, or JBOSS for the Java server piece (Tomcat would also work fine).

Comment: Why?  Java web servers should not feel much difference between the different Windows versions.

Comment: this is plain wrong. would downvote if poster had reputation.